# angular - How to get the value of a variable declared inside a component, to a service file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

How do I access/get a value of a variable declared inside a component to a service file? I googled related to this topic but couldn't find any relevant solution for this

***mylib.component.ts***

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'srr-mylib',
  template: `
    <h1> {{counter}} </h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=counterIncrease()>Increase</button>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class MylibComponent implements OnInit {

  counter: number = 0   // this is the variable that I need to get/access
                        // from the service file
  constructor( ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
   
  }

  counterIncrese() {
    this.counter = this.counter + 1;
  }
  
}
```

***mylib.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MylibService { 

  constructor() { }

  getCounter(){
    //This is function that need to use that 'counter' variable
  }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you need to access a component variable in the service class seems odd. Why exactly do you need it? Ideally, the variable would be a part of only the service in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the other way around, the way it's usually done, for a variable that should be handled in a service and be accessible in the component, is to declarare the variable in the service and import the the service in the component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MylibService { 

counter: number = 0   // this is the variable

  constructor() { }

}
```

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

//import { MylibService } from 'path to the service'

@Component({
  selector: 'srr-mylib',
  template: `
    <h1> {{this.service.counter}} </h1>  <!--use it in your page-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=counterIncrease()>Increase</button>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class MylibComponent implements OnInit {

  counter: number = 0   //<---this is the variable

  constructor(private service: MylibService) {} //<--- import the service

  ngOnInit(){
   
  }
  counterIncrease() {
    this.service.counter++; //<---set it
  }
  
}
```

The variable is declared in the service and you are able to change/access it in both the service and the component as well as in the template, if you increase the counter via button, the changes will reflect in the service and therefore in the component.

Comment: I think OP wants it the other way round. Variable from component needs to be accessed in the service class.